# Histogram generation

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, generation

Write the shortest program that generates a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) (a graphical representation of the distribution of data).

**Rules:**

- Must generate a histogram based on the character length of the words (punctuation included)
  input into the program. (If a word is 4 letters long, the bar representing the number 4 increases by 1)
- Must display bar labels that correlate with the character length the bars represent.
- All characters must be accepted.
- If the bars must be scaled, there needs to be some way that is shown in the histogram.

**Examples:**

```
$ ./histogram This is a hole in one!
1 |#
2 |##
3 |
4 |###

$./histogram Extensive word length should not be very problematic.
1 |
2 |#
3 |#
4 |##
5 |
6 |##
7 |
8 |
9 |#
10|
11|
12|#

./histogram Very long strings of words should be just as easy to generate a histogram just as short strings of words are easy to generate a histogram for.
1 |##
2 |#######
3 |#
4 |#######
5 |###
6 |#
7 |##
8 |##
9 |##
```

Comment: Please write a specification rather than giving a single example which, solely by virtue of being a single example, cannot express the range of acceptable output styles, and which doesn't guarantee to cover all corner cases. It's good to have a few test cases, but it's even more important to have a good spec.

Comment: @PeterTaylor More examples given.

Comment: 1. This is tagged [tag:graphical-output], which means that it's about drawing on the screen or creating an image file, but your examples are [tag:ascii-art]. Is either acceptable? (If not then plannabus might not be happy). 2. You define punctuation as forming countable characters in a word, but you don't state which characters separate words, which characters may and may not occur in the input, and how to handle characters which may occur but which are not alphabetic, punctuation, or word separators. 3. Is it acceptable, required, or prohibited to rescale the bars to fit in a sensible size?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I didn't tag it ascii-art, because it really isn't "art". Phannabus's solution is just fine.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've added in some rules based on what you described.  So far, all the solutions here adhere to all of the rules still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## K, 35

```
{(1+!|/g)#`$(#:'=g:#:'" "\:x)#'"#"}
```

.

```
k){(1+!|/g)#`$(#:'=g:#:'" "\:x)#'"#"}"Very long strings of words should be just as easy to generate a histogram just as short strings of words are easy to generate a histogram for."
1| ##
2| #######
3| #
4| #######
5| ###
6| #
7| ##
8| ##
9| ##
```

.

A longer example

```
k){(1+!|/g)#`$(#:'=g:#:'" "\:x)#'"#"}"Please write a specification rather than giving a single example which, solely by virtue of being a single example, cannot express the range of acceptable output styles, and which doesnt guarantee to cover all corner cases. Its good to have a few test cases, but its even more important to have a good spec."
1 | #####
2 | ######
3 | #######
4 | ########
5 | ######
6 | ##############
7 | ###
8 | #
9 | ##
10| #
11|
12|
13| #
```

Comment: What happens if there are words with more than 9 letters?

Comment: It works for words of any length

Answer (score 6):

## R, <s>55</s> 47 characters

```
hist(a<-sapply(scan(,""),nchar),br=.5+0:max(a))
```

Luckily R comes with a plot function `hist` for histograms, here supplied with a `breaks` argument where the breaks are 0.5, 1.5, ... until max(input)+0.5. `sapply(scan(,""),nchar)` takes an input (as stdin), separates it following the spaces and count the number of characters of each element.

Examples:

```
hist(a<-sapply(scan(,""),nchar),br=.5+0:max(a))
1: Extensive word length should not be very problematic.
9: 
Read 8 items
```

[image]

```
hist(a<-sapply(scan(,""),nchar),br=.5+0:max(a))
1: Very long strings of words should be just as easy to generate a histogram just as short strings of words are easy to generate a histogram for.
28: 
Read 27 items
```

[image]

#### Edit:

A variation at **71 characters** with an axis label at each possible value:

```
hist(a<-sapply(scan(,""),nchar),br=.5+0:max(a),ax=F);axis(1,at=1:max(a))
```

[image]

Comment: I love when a normally verbose language takes the lead!

Comment: This doesn't comply with the specification, however...

Comment: @Doorknob which specification doesn't it comply with?

Comment: The example testcases.

Comment: They are examples, not specifications...

Answer (score 5):

### Python - 83 characters

Seems that we can take input from anywhere, so this takes input during execution, rather than from the command line, and uses Ejrb's suggestion to shorten it by 8.

```
s=map(len,raw_input().split())
c=0;exec'c+=1;print"%3d|"%c+"#"*s.count(c);'*max(s)
```

#### Python - 91 characters

This will fall over with quotes.

```
import sys;s=map(len,sys.argv[1:])
for i in range(1,max(s)+1):print"%3d|"%i+'#'*s.count(i)
```

Input:

```
> python hist.py Please write a specification rather than giving a single example which, solely by virtue of being a single example, cannot express the range of acceptable output styles, and which doesnt guarantee to cover all corner cases. Its good to have a few test cases, but its even more important to have a good spec.
```

Output:

```
  1|#####
  2|######
  3|#####
  4|##########
  5|######
  6|#############
  7|####
  8|#
  9|##
 10|#
 11|
 12|
 13|#
```

Comment: nice, you can shave off 4 chars by reworking your second line (no algorithm change) to use `exec` and string concatenation: `c=0;exec'c+=1;print"%3d|"%c+"#"*s.count(c);'*max(s)`

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell - 126 characters

```
p[d]=[' ',d];p n=n
h l=[1..maximum l]>>= \i->p(show i)++'|':(l>>=($"#").drop.abs.(i-))++"\n"
main=interact$h.map length.words
```

This takes the input from `stdin`, not the command line:

```
& head -500 /usr/share/dict/words | runhaskell 15791-Histogram.hs 
 1|##
 2|##
 3|######
 4|###############
 5|################################################
 6|###############################################################
 7|###################################################################
 8|###########################################################################
 9|#############################################################
10|##########################################################
11|#########################################################
12|#########################
13|#######
14|###
15|#####
16|###
17|#
18|
19|#
20|#
```

Comment: Looks good to me! +1

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 56

```pl
$d[y///c].='#'for@ARGV;printf"%2d|$d[$_]
",$_ for+1..$#d
```

Added @manatwork's rewrite and literal newline suggestion, thank you very much! Added @chinese_perl_goth's updates.

Usage: save as hist.pl and run `perl hist.pl This is a test`

Example output:

```
$perl ~/hist.pl This is a test of the histogram function and how it will count the number of words of specific lengths. This sentence contains a long word 'complexity'.
 1|##
 2|#####
 3|####
 4|######
 5|##
 6|#
 7|
 8|#####
 9|#
10|
11|#
```

Comment: Why not use [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html)? You could spare some characters on formatting. And some more by changing from hash to array: `$d[y///c]++for@ARGV;shift@d;printf"%2d|%s\n",++$i,"#"x$_ for@d`.

Comment: Can I see an example of this program at work?

Comment: @manatwork `printf` didn't occur to me at all and for some reason I didn't think I could get the effect I wanted with an array, amazing!
@syb0rg adding now

Comment: golfed some more, got it down to 57 bytes:
`$d[y///c].='#'for@ARGV;printf"%2d|$d[$_]\n",$_ for+1..$#d`

Comment: @chineseperlgoth thank you! Updated the post! Not sure why building the string directly didn't occur to me!

Comment: We missed just the simplest trick: use a literal newline instead of `\n` to spare 1 more character. I mean like this: http://pastebin.com/496z2a0n

Answer (score 3):

### APL (42)

```
⎕ML←3⋄K,⊃⍴∘'▓'¨+⌿M∘.=K←⍳⌈/M←↑∘⍴¨I⊂⍨' '≠I←⍞
```

Could be shorter if I could omit lines where the value is 0.

Explanation:

- `⎕ML←3`: set the migration level to 3 (this makes `⊂` (partition) more useful).
- `I⊂⍨' '≠I←⍞`: read input, split on spaces
- `M←↑∘⍴¨`: get the size of the first dimension of each item (word lengths), and store in `M`
- `K←⍳⌈/M`: get the numbers from 1 to to the highest value in `M`, store in `K`
- `+⌿K∘.=M`: for each value in `M`, see how many times it is contained in `K`.
- `⊃⍴∘'▓'¨`: for each value in that, get a list of that many `▓`s, and format it as a matrix.
- `K,`: prepend each value in `K` to each row in the matrix, giving the labels.

Output:

```
      ⎕ML←3⋄K,⊃⍴∘'▓'¨+⌿M∘.=K←⍳⌈/M←↑∘⍴¨I⊂⍨' '≠I←⍞
This is a hole in one!
1 ▓  
2 ▓▓ 
3    
4 ▓▓▓
      ⎕ML←3⋄K,⊃⍴∘'▓'¨+⌿M∘.=K←⍳⌈/M←↑∘⍴¨I⊂⍨' '≠I←⍞
Very long strings of words should be just as easy to generate a histogram just as short strings of words are easy to generate a histogram for.
1 ▓▓     
2 ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓
3 ▓      
4 ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓
5 ▓▓▓    
6 ▓      
7 ▓▓     
8 ▓▓     
9 ▓▓
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3.3 (93)

```
a=[len(i) for i in input().split()]
for i in range(1,max(a)+1):
 print(i,'|',"#"*a.count(i))
```

Output:
(the first line is the input string)

```
Very long strings of words should be just as easy to generate a histogram just as short strings of words are easy to generate a histogram for.
1 | ##
2 | #######
3 | #
4 | #######
5 | ###
6 | #
7 | ##
8 | ##
9 | ##
```

It doesn't justify numbers as Lego Stormtroopr's Python solution (which is also shorter than mine), but it's my first entry ever in a golfing contest, so I might as well leave it here I guess :)

Comment: Could you edit in an example of a generated histogram by this program?

Comment: Yes, but I just noticed it has one problem: it doesn't justify the numbers as Lego Stormtroopr's solution, so I'm actually thinking about retiring the answer.

Comment: As long as there are labels for the represented bars, the answer is acceptable.

Comment: Ok, done then! :)

Comment: This takes input from input, not from arguments. Is this valid @syb0rg ?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Yes, as long as the histogram is accurate, any input is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

### J, <strike>48</strike> <strike>47</strike> <strike>46</strike> <strike>45</strike> 43 characters

```
(;#&'#')/"1|:((],[:+/=/)1+[:i.>./)$;._1' ',
```

Usage:

```
   (;#&'#')/"1|:((],[:+/=/)1+[:i.>./)$;._1' ','Very long strings of words should be just as easy to generate a histogram just as short strings of words are easy to generate a histogram for.'
┌─┬───────┐
│1│##     │
├─┼───────┤
│2│#######│  
├─┼───────┤
│3│#      │
├─┼───────┤
│4│#######│
├─┼───────┤
│5│###    │
├─┼───────┤
│6│#      │
├─┼───────┤
│7│##     │
├─┼───────┤
│8│##     │
├─┼───────┤
│9│##     │
└─┴───────┘
```

Comment: Tacit, 38 `[:((](;#&'#')"0[:+/=/)1+[:i.>./)#@>@;:` : [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYw9D4IwGAZ3fsUTSCwNWnAtgZCYODk5uBCHKuUrSJO@JYZfX5lcTBxuu7vRh4K1KCQY9sggNw4Cp@vl7GsZx/c4j3YsYjzMapmkRcqPSS0HUYqUR1VZ5dLzgAoBdtN2xWTmDuTsMHcE0@JtbEOg3ixTg4fGuJCDImhFK5xBp2dtldNQ6AdyprPq9ZW2zLrf279WsCDQz96gBfkP "J – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>98</s> 85

```
a=$*.group_by &:size
1.upto(a.max[0]){|i|b=a.assoc i
puts"%-2i|#{b&&?#*b[1].size}"%i}
```

Not golfed much. Will golf more later.

```
c:\a\ruby>hist This is a test for the histogram thingy. yaaaaaaaaaaaay
1 |#
2 |#
3 |##
4 |##
5 |
6 |
7 |#
8 |
9 |#
10|
11|
12|
13|
14|#
```

Comment: Works nicely (++voteCount). Anything I could do to word the question better?

Comment: @syb0rg IMO the question is worded fine, the examples speak for themselves. Although your last once seems to have an error... I count 2 8-letter words (generate and generate) and 2 9-letter words (histogram, histogram)

Comment: Cool. You could change `b ?(?#*b[1].size):''` with `b&&?#*b[1].size`.

Answer (score 2):

### Powershell, <s>97</s> 93

```
$a=@{};$args-split ' '|%{$a[$_.length]++};1..($a.Keys|sort)[-1]|%{"{0,-2} |"-f $_+"#"*$a[$_]}
```

Example:

```
PS Z:\> .\hist.ps1 This is an example of this program running
1  |
2  |###
3  |
4  |##
5  |
6  |
7  |###
```

Comment: Can I see an example of this program running?

Comment: @syb0rg Sure, I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Looks good! +1 to you!

Comment: Nice. You could remove extra spaces and save 6 bytes `$a=@{};-split$args|%{$a[$_.length]++};1..($a.Keys|sort)[-1]|%{"{0,-2}|"-f$_+"#"*$a[$_]}`

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica 97

```
Histogram["" <> # & /@ StringCases[StringSplit[InputString[]], WordCharacter] /. 
a_String :> StringLength@a]
```

When I input text of the Declaration of Independence as a single string (through cut and paste, of course), the output generated was:

[image: declaration of independence]

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 79

```
(1..(w=$*.group_by &:size).max[0]).map{|i|puts"%2i|#{?#*w.fetch(i,[]).size}"%i}
```

Example run:

```
$ ruby hist.rb Histograms, histograms, every where, nor any drop to drink.
 1|
 2|#
 3|##
 4|#
 5|#
 6|##
 7|
 8|
 9|
10|
11|##
```

Please see my Forth submission for a laugh.

Answer (score 2):

### Forth, 201

This was fun but my Ruby submission is more competitive.  ;-)

```
variable w 99 cells allot w 99 cells erase : h begin
1 w next-arg ?dup while swap drop dup w @ > if dup w
! then cells + +! repeat w @ 1+ 1 ?do i . 124 emit i
cells w + @ 0 ?do 35 emit loop cr loop ; h
```

Sample run:

```
$ gforth histo.fth Forth words make for tough golfing!
1 |
2 |
3 |#
4 |#
5 |###
6 |
7 |
8 |#
```

Max word length is 99.

Answer (score 2):

**Ruby 1.8.7,  74**

A slightly different take than the other ruby solutions:

```
i=0;$*.map{|v|v.size}.sort.map{|v|$><<(i+1..v).map{|n|"
%2i:"%i=n}+['#']}
```

output:

```
ruby hist.rb `head -400 /usr/share/dict/words`

 1:#
 2:###
 3:######
 4:#############################
 5:#####################################################
 6:############################################################
 7:########################################################################
 8:######################################################
 9:############################################################
10:########################
11:###########################
12:######
13:#####
```

Comment: I didn't see this submission initially, sorry! +1

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (<strike>159</strike> 133)

Definitely not competitive, but so far the only JavaScript solution. Thanks to @manatwork for the tip on using `String.replace`.

```
prompt(o=[]).replace(/\S+/g,function(p){o[l=p.length]=(o[l]||'')+'#'});for(i=1;i<o.length;)console.log(i+(i>9?"|":" |")+(o[i++]||""))
```

#### Input

> Code Golf is a question and answer site for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of programming puzzles and their solutions.

#### Output

```
1 |##
2 |#######
3 |#########
4 |########
5 |######
6 |###
7 |####
8 |####
9 |
10|#
11|###
```

Comment: Indeed, this is not really a field where JavaScript excels. But with `replace()` instead of `split()`+`for` and `Array` instead of `Object`+separate length variable can be reduced with a few characters: `prompt(o=[]).replace(/\S+/g,function(p){o[l=p.length]=(o[l]||"")+"#"});for(i=1;i<o.length;)console.log(i+(i>9?"|":" |")+(o[i++]||""))`. (And even shorter in Harmony: `prompt(o=[]).replace(/\S+/g,p=>o[l=p.length]=(o[l]||"")+"#");for(i=1;i<o.length;)console.log(i+(i>9?"|":" |")+(o[i++]||""))`.)

Comment: @manatwork Nice abuse of `.length` there.

Answer (score 1):

#### Pure bash, <s>120</s> 107 bytes

```
d=$*;d=${d//[ -z]/#};for a;do((b[${#a}]++));done;e=${!b[*]};for((i=0;i++<${e##* };)){ echo $i ${d:0:b[i]};}
```

or

```
d=$*
d=${d//[ -z]/#}
for a;do((b[${#a}]++));done
e=${!b[*]}
for((i=0;i++<${e##* };)){
echo $i ${d:0:b[i]}
}
```

or

```
d=$*;d=${d//[ -z]/#};for a;do((b[${#a}]++));done;e=${!b[*]}
for((i=0;i++<${e##* };)){ echo $i ${d:0:b[i]};}
```

Sample:

```
./histogram.sh Very long strings of words should be just as easy to generate a histogram just as short strings of words are easy to generate a histogram for.
1 ##
2 #######
3 #
4 #######
5 ###
6 #
7 ##
8 ##
9 ##
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 162

```
<?php error_reporting(0);$b=0;while($argv[$b])$c[strlen($argv[++$b])]++;for($t=1;$t<=max(array_keys($c));$t++)echo $t.'|'.($c[$t]?str_repeat('#',$c[$t]):'')."\n";
```

Usage:

```
php histogram.php Very long strings of words should be just as easy to generate a histogram just as short strings of words are easy to generate a histogram for.
1|##
2|#######
3|#
4|#######
5|###
6|#
7|##
8|##
9|##
```

Answer (score 1):

## [8th](https://8th-dev.com/), 162 bytes

**Code**

```
a:new ( args s:len nip tuck a:@ ( 0 ) execnull rot swap n:1+ a:! ) 0 argc n:1- loop 
a:len n:1- ( dup . "|" . a:@ ( 0 ) execnull "#" swap s:* . cr ) 1 rot loop bye
```

**Usage**

```
$ 8th histogram.8th Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita mi ritrovai per una selva oscura
```

**Output**

```
1|
2|##
3|####
4|#
5|##
6|###
7|
8|#
```

**Ungolfed code** (**SED** is Stack Effect Diagram)

```
a:new               \ create an empty array 
( 
    args s:len      \ length of each argument
                    \ SED: array argument lengthOfArgument
    nip             \ SED: array lengthOfArgument
    tuck            \ SED: lengthOfArgument array lengthOfArgument
    a:@             \ get item array at "lengthOfArgument" position
    ( 0 ) execnull  \ if null put 0 on TOS
                    \ SED: lengthOfArgument array itemOfArray
    rot             \ SED: array itemOfArray lengthOfArgument    
    swap            \ SED: array lengthOfArgument itemOfArray
    n:1+            \ increment counter for the matching length
    a:!             \ store updated counter into array 
) 0 argc n:1- loop  \ loop through each argument
\ print histogram
a:len n:1- ( dup . "|" . a:@ ( 0 ) execnull "#" swap s:* . cr ) 1 rot loop 
bye                 \ exit program
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 28 bytes

```
Ṡz+öTT' msŀSomȯ:'|R'##oḣ▲mLw
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AWMAnP9odXNr///huaB6K8O2VFQnIG1zxYBTb23IrzonfFInIyNv4bij4paybUx3////RXh0ZW5zaXZlIHdvcmQgbGVuZ3RoIHNob3VsZCBub3QgYmUgdmVyeSBwcm9ibGVtYXRpYy4)

Husk is an ASCII art language.

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 31 bytes ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
(I,'#'⍴⍤0⍨1⊥⊢∘.=I←⍳⌈/)'\S+'⎕S 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc6xSgQxEAbg3qcYsYiirh7WViK4rXtY2eTcSTaSyxxJ7nRr4TgWc2ghWIuChWChT@CjzIusuwfaCMIwxcx8PyMndrespSXdtpv5jtgQnD45Pe9zeh1w88LNEy8es8Oc53ecPvh2sbclzottwcuHAgatWs2X3Nxweuvo1/sBz@/75elR14cnedEqMaxMgK4kVGQRjANyuC7WlDi@juiCmSFckS/BotOxglDR1JbgKMIIYYa@homnkcWxjOYi6@FZP7TkNITojdMBSK0ywo/u5OU0RJABUIYaIoFGh15G7B8xIZL2cvx71DEf/6ZJj/97RT4T3w)

`'\S+'⎕S 1` **S**earch for runs of non-**S**pace characters, returning the length of each

`(`…`)` apply the following tacit function to that list of lengths:

`⌈/` the largest number (lit. maximum reduction)

`⍳` the indices 1…that

`I←` let `I` denote that function

`⊢∘.=` equality table of word lengths vertically and possible word lengths horizontally

`1⊥` sum the columns (lit. evaluate in base 1, with each row representing a digit)

`'#'⍴⍤0⍨` use each element to reshape the hash character, then stack the results and pad

`I,` prepend the result of `I` (i.e. all the possible lengths) as an additional column on the left